# Testing angular components templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, sinon

I'm having an issue testing this template html. I'm using karma and sinon. I'm getting this **Unknown provider: _Provider <- _ <- service** error.

Here is my component:

```
angular.
  .module('app.component.thing-foo')
  .component('thingFoo', {
    templateUrl: 'components/thing-foo/thing-foo.html',
    controller: ThingFooController,
    bindings: {
      thing: '<',
      onSelect: '&'
    }
  });

function ThingFooController($log, service) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.$onInit = $onInit;
  ctrl.$onChanges = $onChanges;
  ctrl.thingList = [];

  function $onInit(){
    getThingList();
  }

  function $onChanges(changesObj){
    if (changesObj.thing) {
      ctrl.thing = angular.copy(changesObj.thing.currentValue);        
  }

  function getThingList(){
    service.getThings()
     .then(function (result) {
       ctrl.thingList = result.things;
     }, function (error) {
       $log.error('Did not work: $0', error);
     })
  }

  function selectionChanged(selected) {
    ctrl.onSelect({thing: selected});
  }
}
```

thing-foo.html:

```
<span ui-dropdown class="dropdown-toggle">
  <a href id="query-menu-label" ui-dropdown-toggle>
    Thing Picker <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul calss="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="query-menu-label" role="menu">
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="thing in $ctrl.thingList">
      <a role="menuitem" ng-click="$ctrl.selectionChanged(thing)">{{ thing }}</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
</span>
```

I'm including the parts of the spec file that are failing:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$componentController_, _$rootScope_){
  $compile = _$compile_;
  $componentController = _$componentController_;
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

beforeEach(function(){
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  element = angular.element('<thing-foo></thing-foo>');
  service = {
   getThings: sinon.stub();
  };
  locals = {
   service: service
  };
});

it('loads html', function(){
 var tag = $compile(element)(scope);
 scope.$apply();
 expect(tag.html()).to.exist();
});
```

There's a lot of code here but I wanted to make sure I included everything. I think the problem is the $ctrl.getThingList in the ng-repeat. Am I supposed to inject the service some how? If so how do I do that? I don't have a lot of practice with writing unit tests for angular. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but maybe try to configure $provider to inject your service?
Something like this:

```
// Put this before your first beforeEach
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
   $provide.value('service', service);
}
```

Comment: 1. what will this do? I'm just trying to understand the process. 
2. I added this line and now I'm getting 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'service.getThings'). I'm guessing I need to stub out the getThings since it's not really returning anything in the test

Comment: 1. This will tell the $provider which is responsible to inject services, to use your service stub in the test context.
2. May this be a typo in your service definition? I see you have there "getThings =" instead of "getThings : "

Comment: It is. I'll update my question. It should be getThings: